# Laravel model "start" date attribute being changed

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a controller which is updating a model through a request object. It looks

```
$save_series = Series::where('id','=',$request->input('data.item.id'))->with('booking')->first();
$save_series->name              = $request->input('data.item.name');
$save_series->color                 = str_replace('#', '', $request->input('data.item.color'));
$save_series->production_company    = $request->input('data.item.production_company');
$save_series->booking->start        = $request->input('data.item.booking.start');
$save_series->booking->end          = $request->input('data.item.booking.end');
$save_series->booking->save();
$save_series->save();
```

When I save this the related "booking " object is updated. If the "end" date attribute is changed, then the "start" attribute's time is set to the current time; this shouldn't be the case! It seems to be ignoring the parsed $request start time completely.

On the related model to the booking I have put a setter mutator to see if the issue resides before that point - the date is being parsed correctly, yet once it hits the database it has changed. My setting (just for this test) looks like this:

```
public function setStartAttribute($time) {
    error_log(":::::::::::TEST BELOW:");
    error_log($time);
    return $time;
}
```

The error log result is:

```
PHP message: :::::::::::TEST BELOW:
PHP message: 2016-10-27 00:00:00
```

Yet the database field of "start" for this record reads:

```
2016-10-27 13:07:53
```

Please can someone explain what on earth is happening here; I'm completely and utterly lost!

-- **Additional information as requested** --

Migration causing issue:

```
Schema::create('calendar_events', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('calendar_event_type')->references('id')->on('calendar_event_types');
    $table->timestampTz('start');
    $table->timestampTz('end');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Migration resolution which fixed the issue:

```
Schema::create('calendar_events', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('calendar_event_type')->references('id')->on('calendar_event_types');
    $table->dateTime('start');
    $table->dateTime('end');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I'm presuming this has something to do with MySQL support for timestampTz and the format I was sending it to the database. Having changed this my problem is now resolved, thanks so much @FrankProvost!

I'm presuming it is now not possible to maintain timezones. In my use case timezones will not be a problem, but it would be nice to have.

Comment: The only thing wich can explain this, is your time formatt is 00h-12h

Comment: The `$time` datetime format is probably the issue

Comment: @ThibaultDumas is the "2016-10-27 13:07:53" being parsed an issue? Is it expecting a Carbon instance or something other?

Comment: ^ also @Wistar for above comment.

Comment: I think i remember that i also had this problem once. Add your migration to the question please. Did you add timestamps (other than the default ones) to the table BEFORE you create the default timestamps? Probably your sql table is set to update to current time on change.

Comment: @FrankProvost thanks so much - that has solved my problem. I've added additional info to the original question.

Comment: is this normal that your error log time contain a ' " ' at the end ?

Comment: @ThibaultDumas, I truncated that error as it goes on to say some environmental stuff which seemed irrelevant: 'PHP message: 2016-10-27 00:00:00" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.42.1, server: ....' (again, truncated). I have since solved my original issue (added info to question). - to confirm, that quote is not part of my string. Good spot!

Comment: i ll quickly add it as question to make it more visible :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the reason for this, but when adding additional timestamps (besides the default created and updated at) you should add the additional ones AFTER adding the default timestamps.

Otherwise it seems like the table sets the "set current timestamp on update" flag to the wrong column.

Instead of

```
$table->timestamp('my_custom_date');
$table->timestamps();
```

Always go for

```
$table->timestamps();
$table->timestamp('my_custom_date');
```